# want to increase delay timings for hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three level of ul li.

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
     <ul>
        <li>
        <li>
           <ul>
             <li>
```

I want to increase the hover timings i.e when i hover over the second level li the delay time for hover has to be increased until i reach its children i.e third level

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: I think he's talking about some kind of dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have javascripe code using `mouseover()`/`mouseout()` or `hover()`:
Get the hoverIntent plugin and use `element.hoverIntent(overfunc, outfunc)`

Answer (score 0):

When you're using jquery make sure you're using [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) in these cases.  `mouseover` and `mouseout` fire **even when entering a child element**.  If you have code to hide things, you wouldn't want it to run in a menu at that point, you want it to run when you leave the `<li>` completely and consider a child as still being inside...that's what `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` do :)

There's also a shortcut for this called [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which uses the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events like this:

```
$(selector).hover(mouseenterFunc, mouseleaveFunc);
```

Here's an example:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).children().slideUp();
});
```

[You can see the above code in a quick demo against your posted tree here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt9Va/)